# Combine 2 datapoints to a single variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to export information about servers into a report using                                          Pscribo. This works perfectly for a single value, but I have a variable $msg is made up of 3 different values. When I pass the $msg to Pscribo I get blank values for ServerName & Message (Message has no text tbh)

[image: Output]

```
$msg

ServerName Status Message
---------- ------ -------
POD-1-CS01   OK     No Error
POD-1-CS03   OK     No Error
```

This is made up by 3 variables.

```
PS C:\> $msg.ServerName
POD-1-CS01
POD-1-CS03
```

```
PS C:\> $msg.Status    
OK
OK
```

```
PS C:\> $msg.Message    
No Error
No Error
```

I want to combine the 3 values for each replication partner, keeping the formatting of the

POD-1-CS01   OK     No Error
POD-1-CS03   OK     No Error

Not sure how to combine the 3 values and pass this to PowerShell as a single string of text.

Thoughts?

Comment: From the table output shown, it looks like `$msg` contains _2 objects_, each of which has _3 properties_. [`$msg.ServerName` doesn't actually exist, but is calculated on the fly from `$msg[0].ServerName` and `$msg[1].ServerName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.3)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to space-concatenate the property values of each object stored in `$msg`:

```bash
$msg.ForEach({ $_.psobject.Properties.Value -join ' ' })
```

Note the use of the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views) in combination with [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) in order to retrieve all property values.

Given that the `.Message` property values contain spaces themselves, the resulting strings aren't suited to *programmatic* processing, however.